React Chart - Radar/Spider graph customization
I am using react radar chart, but I am unable to customized it, I refer so many stackoverflow content, but no luch,
I need to remove points from graph,
If label size is big, then it cuts from browser,
I need to remove ticks number from graph
Adding problem link here
radar chart codesanbox
